# Bash - Convert date to timestamp

Tags: bash, date, timestamp

I want to convert a date into a timestamp.

My input looks something like:

```
Mon Sep 30 17:37:39 2019
```

And I want to take that timestamp and check how many days that have passed since today.

What I tried:

```
data = "$(date --date "$(echo "$info" | grep "Date added: *" | sed 's/Date added\:\s//i' | awk '{$1=$1};1')" '+%H')"
final = $(expr $(date '+%H') - $data)
```

However this will in some cases print out values such as -9, -3, -12 etc and for todays date it currently print out "08". Any ideas how to solve this?

Something that is worth mentioning is that I dont really care about exact hours if that complicates things, I am more interesting in how many days that have passed.

**EDIT**

Current solution (does not handle hours which is a bummer). I extract the Day, Month and Year and organise it into YYYY-MM-DD and thereafter convert it to a timestamp. This solution do not handle hours which I do want in the end.

```
$(( ($(expr $(date '+%s')) - $(date -d "$(printf '%s\n' "$date_added" | awk '{
        printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", $5, \
        (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3,$3}')" +"%s")) / 3600 ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding a generic solution(after doing some testing and searches(google)), could you please try following which will provide exact days, hours, minutes and seconds difference between 2 dates.

```
prev=$(date --date='Mon Aug 30 14:46:39 2019' +"%s")
today=$(date +%s)
number_of_seconds=$(( ($today - $prev ) ))
printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($number_of_seconds/86400)) $(($number_of_seconds%86400/3600)) $(($number_of_seconds%3600/60)) $(($number_of_seconds%60))
```

Output is as follows(I am in on my `aws` server with UTC time zone in it).

```
56d:17h:29m:14s
##### Where my system's date is: #####
date
Sat Oct 26 08:16:14 UTC 2019
```

---

---

Could you please try following once.

```
prev=$(date --date='Mon Sep 30 17:37:39 2019' +"%s")
today=$(date +%s)
echo $(( ($today - $prev )/(60*60*24) ))
```

Output I am getting it `25` since I am in IST time zone and it is around 12:20 PM IST as of now. Also variable names are self explanatory, where prev variable is for date which OP has asked to get the difference from today's date.

***Explanation of getting days difference:***

1. First I am passing OP's given date to `date --date...` command to get it in [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and saving it into `prev` bash variable.
2. Now creating `today` bash variable which has today's epoch time.
3. Then taking difference of these 2 variables epoch time values and converting them into exact Number of days by dividing `60*60*24` to its difference epoch value.

---

---

***NOTE:*** Tested on different dates for testing like for 30th Aug 2019:

```
prev=$(date --date='Mon Aug 30 17:37:39 2019' +"%s")
today=$(date +%s)
echo $(( ($today - $prev )/(60*60*24) ))
56
```

Comment: I like the idea, but it doesnt seem to work, I you try other dates you will see that the nuimber 25 will occur again. Thinking that the format on the date is wrong. I found a temporary solution but it does not handle hours (just days), will update the post with what I found.

Comment: @Fredrik, Hey I just checked for another day and number of days are coming perfectly. Only thing which I need to edit/add is for hours calculation, which I will add in sometime and let you know then.

Comment: Alright, tried a few things and it works very well! Any ideas how I can include hours?

Comment: @Fredrik, yeah I am looking into it buddy, will let you know in few mins:)

Comment: Did some further testing at I think the code you made actually do handle hours/minutes/seconds too. Not 100% sure but one time is: Fri Oct 25 22:24:20  amd compare it to now that is (1572077267 - 1572042260) /3600 => 9.69, It is two hours late but I guess that is due to time difference from the site I used. But since it is not 0 means it do handle hours within a day :)

Comment: @Fredrik, Cool, glad that it helped you. As promised I added a generic solution now, which should provide more exact details in terms of days,hours , mins and seconds. Lemme know in case of any queries,  even I am going to save this link for my reference for future use :)